# A problem in using ClipRRect() in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have used ClipRRect for rounded corners in the UI. The ClipRRect wraps topContent and bottomContent are a stack and a Column respectively. But, the bottom corners are not round. What may be the reason behind this?

[image: this is the screenshot]

The cardModel class is used to store the image path in this case.

```
    class FeaturedCard extends StatelessWidget {
     final FeaturedCardModel cardModel;
     final double parallaxPercent;

  FeaturedCard({
    this.cardModel,
    this.parallaxPercent = 0.0, //default value
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topContent = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 10.0,
            ),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(cardModel.imgUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );

    final bottomContentText = Text(
      'This is the sample text',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
    );

    final bottomContent = Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: Center(
        child:
            bottomContentText,
        ),
      );

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          topContent,
          bottomContent,
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Flutter Inspector and do "Toggle Debug Paint" you will see that the clipping occurs in the blue area below.

You can fix it by giving a size to your clipper.

```
return SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        topContent,
        //bottomContent,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The column that is the child of `ClipRRect` is taking as much space as it can get. so the border radius is applied to the bottom of the screen.
to solve that you just need to set `mainAxisSize` property of `Column` to `MainAxisSize.min`:

```
return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          topContent,
          bottomContent,
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: Container(
    width: 100, // Specify the width
    height: 100, // Specify the height
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'ClipRRect Example',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).